# TypeScript generic Error when writing a decorator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When using React 16 new feature: componentDidCatch, I try write a HOC to abstract the code. And implement it with decorator.
Code below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
export function catcher<P, T extends React.ComponentClass<P>>(Target: T): T {
  class HOC extends Target {

  }
  return HOC;
}
```

and just using it like:

```
@catcher
export class Foo extends React.Component {}
```

BUT, errors occurs

```
[ts] Type 'T' is not a constructor function type.

[ts] Type 'typeof HOC' is not assignable to type 'T'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) say that the first argument to the decorator is a the constructor, so we have to give T a constructor signature. The example in the docs has the constructor returning `{}`, but if we want to make sure the decorator cannot be used on just any type and must be used on a `React.Component` we can have the constructor return a `React.Component`, so any constructor passed will have to return a `React.Component` or compatible (in effect will have to be derived from `React.Component`)

```
export function catcher<S, P, T extends { new (... args:any[]): React.Component<S, P>  }>(constructor:T) {
  class HOC extends constructor {

  }
  return HOC;
}

@catcher
export class Foo extends React.Component {
}

@catcher // Will be an error, Foo2 is not derived from React.Component
export class Foo2  {
}
```

An alternative syntax for the signature of the constructor is:

```
export function catcher<S, P, T extends new (... args:any[]) => React.Component<S, P>>(constructor:T) {
  class HOC extends constructor {

  }
  return HOC;
}
```

Comment: T extends React.ComponentClass<P>  is a constructor signature;   Look at the mobx-react index.d.ts: export function observer<P, TFunction extends React.ComponentClass<P | void>>(
    target: TFunction
): TFunction // decorator signature

Comment: @ZiyuZhou Yes, that is a valid definition for a decorator. If you didn't have the need to create e new class extending the original it would work. The reason mobx-react gets away with that signature is that it only need a valid decorator signature it does the work in JS. If you want to be able to use `T` in the extends clause, Typescript must be able to check that the `constructor` argument is a valid constructor and that can be done by ensuring `constructor` is not just a function but an actual type constructor