# Generic interface that extend another interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

My component interface

```
interface InputProps {
  value?:string,
  onChange?: (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: string) => void;
}
```

I want to write generic type that will contains all props from P and WrappedFieldProps

```
interface FormComponent<P> extends WrappedFieldProps  {
// props from P
// props from WrappedFieldProps
}

/*
// import { WrappedFieldProps } from 'redux-form'
interface WrappedFieldProps {
    input: WrappedFieldInputProps;
    meta: WrappedFieldMetaProps;
}
*/
```

and use it in generic function shouldComponentUpdate

```
export function shouldFormFieldUpdate<P>(props: FormComponentProps<P>, nextProps: FormComponentProps<P>): boolean {
    const { input: { value }, meta: { valid, touched, error }, ...rest } = props;
    let result;
    // compare logic
    return result;
}
```

but I got ts error on rest variable: rest types may only be created from object types

Answer (score 1):

You can define an intersection type for this

```
type  FormComponent<P> = P & WrappedFieldProps ;
export function shouldFormFieldUpdate<P>(props: FormComponent<P>, nextProps: FormComponent<P>): boolean {
    const { input: { value }, meta: { valid, touched, error } } = props;
    let result;
    // compare logic
    return result;
}
```

The limitation of the code above is that you can't use `...rest`. This is a current [limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727)

Comment: Is there any practises to use `...rest` or only usage javascript can resolve it?

Comment: You can use `...res`t, but not the type is defined as I have defined it above. I defined the type this way because Interface can't use generic parameters in the inheritance clause.

Comment: Is it correct that writing generic HOC that using `...rest` is almost impossible?

Comment: @Alekstim Not necessarily you can write generic HOCs, just not this particular one. Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016598/typescript-generic-error-when-writing-a-decorator/47017341#47017341 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869910/how-do-i-properly-set-types-for-higher-order-class-components-in-typescript/48870168#48870168